# Upgrade stuck on "configuring stgit"

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

My upgrade process seems to be stuck. Can't seem to find anything on the Internet about this particular problem.

Here's what I can see.

[image]

I've since killed the process and tried anew.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu0.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up rhythmbox-plugins (2.97-1ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.00-7ubuntu11) ...
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Same deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'fix' the error, I did the following:

Open a new terminal

```
sudo killall dpkg
sudo killall apt
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
Ctrl-C on memtest86+ hang
Ctrl-C on initramfs install hang
sudo update-grub2
```

Then:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`

Courtesy of: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/986833/comments/3

Reboot. No problems on reboot.